# How to replace specific word from String

Tags: java, android

how can I replace a specific word from user input and display it as an asterisk.
This is my code.

```
String[] filteredWords = ["apple", "banana", "orange"];

private String convertWord(String input) {
    StringBuilder asterisk = new StringBuilder();
    for (String filter: filteredWords) {
        if (input.toLowerCase().contains(filter)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < filter.length(); i++) {
                asterisk.append("*");
            }
            input = input.replace(filter, asterisk.toString());
        }
    }

    return input;
}
```

for example the user input or type "This is apple and not orange", the expected output would be "This is ***** and not ******".

but my problem here is when the user type (with a character casing) "This is Apple and not oRaNGE" or "This is aPpLe and not Orange" the output is not changing. The word apple and orange are not being replace with an asterisk.

any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: have you used ignore case

Comment: Or try this out? input = input.replaceAll("(?i)"+filter, asterisk.toString());

Answer (score 6):

I like using regex replacement here, with an alternation containing all your search terms:

```
String[] filteredWords = { "apple", "banana", "orange" };
String regex = "(?i)\\b(?:" + String.join("|", filteredWords) + ")\\b";

private String convertWord(String input) {
    input = input.replaceAll(regex, "*");
    return input;
}

convertWord("Apple watermelon ORANGE boot book pear banana");
```

The output from the above method call is:

```
* watermelon * boot book pear *
```

Comment: Hello, fyi OP wants words replaced by string of  "*" like passwords.

Comment: @dariosicily And my response is: Don't do that.  By retaining the original length of a password, you are still giving away some information about what that password really might be.

Comment: This does not work for example string: "AppLe watermelon orange boot book pear banana". input = input.toLowerCase().replaceAll(regex, "*"); I think that does the trick.

Comment: Agree with you, to avoid misunderstanding I was just saying what OP wrotes in his question.

Comment: @barbwire Then add the `(?i)` flag to the regex pattern, to make is case insensitive, q.v. the updated answer.

Comment: @dariosicily You can add `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);` and replace the body by `return pattern.matcher(input).replaceAll(m -> "*".repeat(m.group().length()));`.

Comment: @saka1029 I am agree with you, I thought about a similar solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] filteredWords = ["apple", "banana", "orange"];

private static String convertWord(String input) {
        StringBuilder asterisk = new StringBuilder();
        String inputInLower = input.toLowerCase();
        for (String filter: filteredWords) {
                if (inputInLower.contains(filter)) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < filter.length(); i++) {
                        asterisk.append("*");
                    }
                    inputInLower = inputInLower.replace(filter, asterisk.toString());
                    asterisk.setLength(0);
                }
            }
            return inputInLower;
        }
```

There was 2 problems I found in your code

1. Your are using the input string which is not converted to lower characters, so array value is not matching. You can solve this by using a new variable as I use in answer or convert to lower before replacing.
2. Second problem was with StringBuilder you have to clear builder after every iteration or else last characters will be append in that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the must easy way it just add in xml option that user can insert only small latter, because if I understand right, you don't carry about latter, you work with words.

So how you can do i, you can add in xml fist line or seconds code line in your java class.

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 "

EditText userText = findViewById(R.id.userText);
String input;
input = userText.getText().toString();
input = input.toLowerCase();
```